# Getting around Babel remapping ES6 "this" to undefined

Tags: javascript, browserify, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm in the process of moving a codebase to ES6 classes.

I am still dealing with some legacy jQuery modules, which have `init` functions attached to them, which are called from the html. The entry point of the code looks like this:

```
import * as moduleOne from './module_one/module_one';
import * as moduleTwo from './module_two/module_two';
import * as moduleThree from './module_three/module_three';
import * as moduleFour from "./module_four/module_four";

window.initjQuery = (mod) => {
    eval(mod).init()
}
```

And in the HTML:

`<script>initjQuery('moduleFour')</script>`

So this works and moduleFour.init() is properly called. But I would like to avoid the use of eval if possible. The problem is that Babel remaps `this` to `undefined` so there is no way for me to do something like:

```
var _this = this;

window.initjQuery = function(mod) {
   _this[mod].init();
}
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: `switch(mod) { case 'moduleFour': ... `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those module names are just variables (in the module scope), no properties of any object. Notice that `this` is `undefined` in modules just as in strict functions.

So you'll want to put those module objects on an explicit object:

```
import * as moduleOne from './module_one/module_one';
import * as moduleTwo from './module_two/module_two';
import * as moduleThree from './module_three/module_three';
import * as moduleFour from "./module_four/module_four";

const modules = {moduleOne, moduleTwo, moduleThree, moduleFour};
window.initjQuery = (mod) => {
    modules[mod].init()
};
```